# How to disable updates in SwiftUI List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm working on a SwiftUI + CoreData application which holds (for several entities) a list view with navigation to an edit view where I can make changes.
I decided to directly pass the managed object from the list to the edit view (observed) to avoid even one more code duplication of listing all attributes. My edit view is able to revert the changes made to the managed object when I go back to list without saving.

However I have a weird behavior: whenever I edit the field which is responsible for the sorting in the list view, e.g. *title*, and this changes the order in the list, the view slides back to list view and immediately forth to edit view. I can see, that the edited item changed position in the list. This happens on the first keypress that changes the title accordingly.
I want to avoid this (because it's distracting and I lose focus on the title field).

Any way to disable updates to the list or at least disable the switching to list and back?

[image]

```
struct GameListView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Game.title, ascending: true),
            NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Game.externalId, ascending: true),
        ],
        animation: .default)
    private var games: FetchedResults<Game>

    @State private var showDetailView = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(games) { game in
                    NavigationLink(destination: GameEditView(game: game)) {
                        HStack {
                            Image("game-icon")
                            Text("\(game.title)")
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(NSLocalizedString("Games", comment: "NavigationBar title"))
        }
    }
}

struct GameEditView: View {
    @ObservedObject var game: Game
    
    @State private var showingCancelSheet = false
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // TODO: add all the attributes of Game
            GameFormView(title: $game.title, onSave: {
                try game.validate()
                try game.save()
                presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            })
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(NSLocalizedString("Edit Game", comment: "NavigationBar title"))
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                Button(action: {
                    if game.hasChanges {
                        self.showingCancelSheet = true
                    } else {
                        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
                    }
                },
                label: {
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                    Text("Games", comment: "Button label back to list of games")
                })
            }
        }
    }
}

struct GameAddView: View {
    @State private var title = ""
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
    @Environment (\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        GameFormView(title: $title, onSave: {
            try Game.validate(title: self.title, game: nil, context: viewContext)
            let game = Game.create(title: self.title, context: viewContext)
            try game.save()
            presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        })
        .navigationBarTitle(NSLocalizedString("New Game", comment: "NavigationBar title"))
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .cancellationAction) {
                Button(action: cancel) {
                    Text("Cancel", comment: "Button label cancel add game")
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func cancel() {
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
}

struct GameFormView: View {
    @Binding var title : String
    // TODO: add all the attributes of Game

    public var onSave: () throws -> Void

    @State private var titleError: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Section(header: Text("Game Title", comment: "Section header")) {
                VStack {
                    TextField(NSLocalizedString("Title", comment: "TextField label game form"), text: $title)
                    if self.titleError != nil {
                        Text(self.titleError!)
                            .fontWeight(.light)
                            .font(.footnote)
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .primaryAction) {
                Button(action: saveForm,
                       label: { Text("Save", comment: "Button label save game") })
            }
        }
    }
    
    func saveForm() {
        do {
            try self.onSave()
        } catch GameValidationError.emptyName {
            self.titleError = NSLocalizedString("Title can't be empty", comment: "Validation error on game")
        } catch GameValidationError.duplicateTitle(_) {
            self.titleError = NSLocalizedString("Title already exists", comment: "Validation error on game")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Unexpected error: \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of binding try to pass game into `GameFormView` and edit it in place, w/o callback to previous view.

Comment: I added `GameAddView` for more clarity. By that I can't use the Form view from the Add view (no object available). `GameFormView` exists to have one view with the layout only.

Comment: BTW: I worked around this by adding `.id(UUID())` to the list, but that feels rather awkward. Something like `beginUpdate..endUpdate` for the list or the managed object would probably be cleaner (unsure).

Comment: ... which led to the fact that deletion isn't possible anymore (EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION) :-(